# Detect if iOS device can play HD video

Tags: javascript, objective-c, video

I've read that 2nd generation iPod Touches are unable to play some types of video (particularly HD) *even if its OS is up-to-date*. I'm still trying to track down the video settings of a third-party stream I will be using, but I've already seen this with two 2nd gen Touches with 4.2.1 unable to play video.

Is there a way to detect from Objective C or JavaScript whether the host device is able to play <strike>a given type of video?</strike> HD video?

EDIT: I've revised my question. I am pretty certain at this point that the problem is HD (or maybe aspect ratio). The problem is that I don't know how to detect what the hardware version is (1st, 2nd or 3rd gen). I can detect the OS version, but it's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr( http://www.modernizr.com/ ) might be able to help you with that

Comment: It looks like Modernizr just uses the video element's `canPlayType()`, which unfortunately just tests the mime type of the video stream. Standard def and HD both have the same mime type, so both would return `probably` when tested. I think the problem is the aspect ratio rather than the encoding properties or mime types.